# insert line into file using rails templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, sed

I am trying to create a rails template that will add code to files at particular line numbers. For example I need to add a route to the config/routes.rb

I have tried sed, gsed(only cause I am on a mac and they say that sed has problems with insert and append), anyway, I was not able to achieve the result I want.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

I have tried several permutations of this command, but none work, here is an example

```
run "gsed '3 a/This is it' config/routes.rb"
```

perhaps even another suggestion

EDIT::::::

ok I took a break and when I came back, after reading up on sed, I realized that I needed to write the stream back to the file, but I was doing this before with,

```
run  "gsed '2 a\
Add this line after 2nd line
' config/routes.rb > config/routes.rb"
```

but the routes file would be blank, so I tried using a different filename(new.routes.rb),

```
run  "gsed '2 a\
Add this line after 2nd line
' config/routes.rb > config/new.routes.rb"
```

and this worked, so I know what to do now.

Comment: which version of rails do you want to support?

Comment: What happens when you try `sed '3 a\This is it' config/routes.rb`?

Comment: nothing happens, I am thinking that the path where the template is run is not right, does anyone know if a rails template file, is executed in the RAILS_ROOT, if not I think I know what to do, but I am not sure how to figure out what the path is.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since line numbers change as your file evolves, it's better to insert your new code before or after existing string expressions.  Inside your template generator, you can do something like this:

```
inject_into_file 'config/application.rb', :before => "  end" do
  "\n    config.logger = Logger.new(config.paths.log.first, 50, 1048576)\n\n"
end
```

Note, you can use :after if :before doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the info, much smarter solution

Answer (score 0):

I have to wonder why you're using sed for this.  Write a Ruby script to open up the file, read it in line by line, make your changes and write the file back out.  About the only problem you're going to have with that is editing a file "in place."  To get around that, open up a [temporary file](http://ruby.about.com/od/beginningruby/a/dir4.htm), write to that file, then move that file over the old file using File.move.

Comment: +1 This is essentially was rails itself does to add routes when you generate a resource.

Comment: can this be done with a rails template?, please understand I am new to the ruby on rails world, just trying to swim out to this little ruby island, without a boat. lol

Answer (score 0):

this will do the trick, just remember to delete the old one and rename the new on in its place

```
run  "gsed '2 a\
Add this line after 2nd line
' config/routes.rb > config/new.routes.rb"
```